# Word crashes on User field in Document Information Panel

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, office-365-develop-tool

I have a SharePoint Hosted application created in Visual Studio 2012 that I deploy to Office365.  The application has a Document Library in it with the following field defined in the schema.xml:

```
<Field Name="Owner" ID="{ac6f29e5-f0ae-4b35-ad0d-6a4be1472046}" DisplayName="Owner" Type="User" Required="FALSE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly">
```

When I create a new document and click on the tick or address book icon on the "Owner" field in the Document Information Panel Word crashes.

> Faulting application name: WINWORD.EXE, version: 15.0.4517.1505, time
>   stamp: 0x51bfecea Faulting module name: PEOPLEDATAHANDLER.DLL,
>   version: 15.0.4515.1000, time stamp: 0x5180c917

Now I'm assuming that this is an issue with SharePoint Hosted Applications and the people picker control in Word.  This would normally reference the UserInfo list of the site behind the scences, but that probably doesn't exist in my SharePoint Hosted Application.

This all works fine in a Document Library I create manually on Office365.

Has anyone else experienced this and managed to overcome it, or is it just a limitation or oversight by Microsoft?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you should add List="UserInfo" to your field declaration. Otherwise you will have problems like: http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/message.aspx?name=fatalerror-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-g

Comment: I tried that same error, but I'm not sure that list exists inside my SharePoint Hosted App.

Comment: The list exists in every web on SharePoint, (you app has an app web, so it will have the list). But as I said, this is not the solution to your current problem, just a heads-up

Comment: If I goto:

my.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

I see the User Information List. But if I goto:

my-7c59c4bf8d659f.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer/MyApp/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

I get a 404 error.  So does my SharePoint Hosted App really have a User Information List ?

Comment: Interesting observation! You would have thought even an app web should have the list.